# Calling Function when view returns from subview | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidappear

I have a 'PopUp' style view which is displayed as a child view so that it appear infront of the parent view controller like this:

```
let popOverView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newProjectPopup") as! AddProjectViewController
self.addChildViewController(popOverView)
popOverView.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popOverView.view)
popOverView.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

To close the popup view I am using

```
self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

This works great besides from the fact that it does not call the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods in the parent view. I need to update information in the parent view controller when the popup is dismissed. How can I do this?

Comment: FYI - you need to call a lot more than just `self.view.removeFromSuperview()` to properly remove the contained view controller and its view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Delegate pattern to update your parent view.

Delegate pattern

```
protocol ParentViewControllerDelegate {
    func didUpdate(data: NSData)
}

class parentViewController: UIViewController, ParentViewControllerDelegate {

    func didUpdate(data: NSData) {
        // Update logic here
    }
}
```

Then in your child view controller you can call the delegate didUpdate function before dismissing it.

Comment: Thanks @koropok , I've implemented what you suggested above. To call it I have created reference to the delegate with 'var delegate: ParentViewControllerDelegate?' in the child view and then run 'delegate?.didUpdate()' right before closing.

Comment: Fixed, I still needed to assign the popOverViews delegate to self before displaying it. 'popOverView.delegate = self'

Comment: yes you need to assign the parent view as the delegate. glad that it's working now.